# Add new contact (other than logged in user) using Caldera Forms linked to CiviCRM under Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

Civi 5.10.4. under Wordpress 5.1.1 multisite network using the plugins Caldera Forms and Caldera Forms CiviCRM. I'm seeking to create a new contact creation form for our incarcerated persons visitation & advocacy program. For example, **one of our program coordinators gets a call or letter from a detained person that coordinator needs to create a new detained person contact record**. The longer term goal is to create a system to track activities like visits, letters, transfers, and complaints. I'm starting by trying to make an interface to create new detained person contacts. I created the detained person contact type, created some of the fields we'll use, and made a profile to contain some of those. Then I created a Caldera Form and mapped the form field names to the detained person contact type.

**When I use the form to create a new contact, it updates my own contact record rather than creating a new record.** I've tried setting the form processor to link to either Contact 1 or Contact 2, but seem to get the same result. I think there's something I'm not understanding about how to set up the processor.

**Can I use Caldera to create a new contact (other than the person logged in)?** If so, how? Additionally, it would be ideal to track who was the logged in user who created the new detained person contact. Do I need to create an activity processor for that?

Thanks in advance for any help and guidance the community can provide on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some tinkering, I think I understand better how this works. I included fields for both a volunteer and a new detained person. Before, there were only fields for collecting information on the new detained person.

Now that there are fields for both individuals: 1) the logged in person filling out the form and 2) the new detained individual.

Next I created two processors: CiviCRM Contact 1 and CiviCRM Contact 2.

Contact 1 I associated with the fields for the volunteer and used name & email as the dedupe rule.

Contact 2 I associated with the detained person CiviCRM contact type and associated with the fields for a new detained person.

By using the processors to define the two contact roles it seems to have worked such that the volunteer's account was unchanged and a new detained person record was created. [This post](https://tadpole.cc/using-caldera-forms-civicrm-for-multiple-contacts/) helped me understand it better. I'd read it before but after going over it several times figured out what was needed. I hope this helps someone else.